# Exit bash loop directly

Tags: bash, function, while-loop

I have the following script

```
#!/bin/bash
    
cat << 'EOF1' > textfile.txt
text1
text2
text3
text4
text5
text6
text7
text8
text9
text10
text11
EOF1
    
function SetNumber () {
while true; do
cat textfile.txt
    
echo -e '\n\nMake a selection'
echo -e '\nSelect a option or Press Enter to Exit'
read -p $'\nSelection : ' NUMB      
echo
case "$NUMB" in
"") if [ -z "$NUMB" ] ; then : ; fi ; break ;;
 *) if [[ $NUMB == text[1-11] ]] ; then CheckNumber
  elif [[ $NUMB =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] && [ ${#NUMB} -ge 1 ] && [ ${#NUMB} -le 2 ] && ((NUMB >= 1 && NUMB <= 11)) ; then CheckNumber
else echo -e ' This is not a valid choice.\n' ; fi ; SetNumber ; break ;;
esac
done
}
    
function CheckNumber () {
if [[ $NUMB =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] ; then NUMB=text$NUMB ; fi
varinteth=$(awk '/^'${NUMB}'$/{print $0}' textfile.txt)
if [ -z "$varinteth" ]
then echo -e '\n You must select one of the available options.\n' ; SetNumber
else awk '!/^'${NUMB}'$/' textfile.txt > temp && mv temp textfile.txt ; fi
}
    
SetNumber
```

If I press 1 it follows the steps and remove text1 from textfile.txt

if I press by mistake 1 again it show me the message to select one of the availables options and returns to the SetNumber function as it should be but if then I press enter to exit it show me the
Make a selection again and I have to press enter again to exit.

as I understand this happens so many times as many I press by mistake an option I have made again

What I have to do to exit directly when I press enter after a mistake ?

p.s. I don't know if my title is the right one but I don't know exactly what title should I put.
If you have a better idea, tell her so I can change it

Comment: looks like you're making recursive/nested function calls (eg, `SetNumber` calls `SetNumber`; `SetNumber` calls `CheckNumber` which calls `SetNumber`) so while the `break` will get you out of the *current* loop for the *current* function call, the `break` does not get you out of the loop of the parent function

Comment: Yes I believe thats my problem but how can I get out of the parent loop and when I come back I can continue working until I press enter to exit?

Comment: a google search on `bash break out of nested functions` brings up several hits, with most of the useful links suggesting the use/testing of return codes to trigger `break`s in parent loops; having said that ... do you *really* want `SetNumber` calling itself if you're already in a `while true` loop (ie, why not print the message and just let the `while true` take care of re-prompting)? ...

Comment: similar question for the `SetNumber>CheckNumber>SetNumber` sequence => just have `CheckNumber` return to `SetNumber` and after the appropriate return code checks let the `while true` take care of re-prompting; eliminate the nested function calls and you're left with a single loop and a single `break`; **NOTE:** may need to adjust the `if/then/else` logic to work with the move from nested recursion to 'basic' looping (eg, limiting the `Check*` functions to just *checking* and returning a code while the parent takes care of `awk/mv/etc` operations)

Comment: Side note: `text[1-11]` doesn’t do what you may think it does.

Comment: Because I am new to bash script programming and do not understand how to do what you suggest, it would probably be good to explain to you exactly what I want to do so that you can help me.

Comment: I want when I select one of the available options either with the name (text1) or with its number (1) to check if this option is available and if yes to remove it with the awk and if not to show me a message that I did not the right choice. And this should be repeated until I press enter to leave.

Comment: I simply do two checks if my choice is correct 
1. If it is within the limits (1-11) and (message: This is not a valid choice)
2. if it is outside the limits (message: You must select one of the available options)
Can you suggest me some code that does it without the problem?